# Как при нажатии на button, чтобы иконка увеличила font-size. Иконка прописана через before .Реализовать это все нужно через Jquery

Tags: jquery

Как при нажатии на button, чтобы иконка увеличила font-size.
Иконка прописана через before.
Реализовать это все нужно через Jquery

```css
.search__form {
  width: 174px;
  position: relative;
}

.search__input {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 9px 25px 9px 9px;
  border: 1px solid #656565;
}

.search__block-btn {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search__block-btn:before {
  content: '\f002';
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #656565;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="search__form" action="#">
  <input class="search__input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <button class="search__block-btn" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Сделать через добавление стилией к иконке или их изменеие?

Comment: нужно чтобы при нажатии на иконку (лупа), у меня скрываеться input, а лупа увеличиваеться в размере

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [CSS переменные](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) и передавать на псевдоэлементы стили через них.

```js
$('.search__block-btn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).css('--search-size', '200%');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.search__form {
  width: 174px;
  position: relative;
}

.search__input {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 9px 25px 9px 9px;
  border: 1px solid #656565;
}

.search__block-btn {
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search__block-btn:before {
  content: '\f002';
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: var(--search-size, 16px);
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #656565;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="search__form" action="#">
  <input class="search__input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <button class="search__block-btn" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Или `transform: scale(1.5)`